# How can i implement Cookie base authentication and jwt in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I want to use both cookie based authentication and `jwt` in my program, used authentication user to access `mvc` controller with login and JWT to access WebApi resource.

I tried using two of them First, my client can login and authenticate with the cookie using username and password. Second access resource from Application with WebApi with Token Bearer but I get an error!

In my `startup.cs` file I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.ConsentCookie.Name = "Cookie";
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
                options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:ClaimsIssuer"];
            });

            services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

                //Token
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
                    options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:ClaimsIssuer"];
                })
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
                 {
                     microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
                     microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
                 })
                .AddGoogle(googleOptions => 
                {
                    googleOptions.ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "g4GZ2#...GD5Gg1x";
                    googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Gender, "gender");
                    googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
                    googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                    {
                        List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens()
                            as List<AuthenticationToken>;
                        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                        {
                            Name = "TicketCreated",
                            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                        });
                        ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:ClaimsIssuer"];
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                    options.Audience = Configuration["Authentication:Audience"];
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {

                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:ValidIssuer"],

                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Authentication:ValidAudience"],

                        ValidateLifetime = true,

                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:SecurityKey"]))
                    };
                });






            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddSession();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        }
```

And I got a token in this controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken(TokenLoginModel model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Token failed to generate");
            var user = await _usermanager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            //var user = true;// (model.Password == "password" && model.Username == "username");
            if (user != null && await _usermanager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var claims = new[]{
                    new Claim("ClaimsIssuer", _configuration.GetSection("Authentication:ClaimsIssuer").Value),
                new Claim(Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,user.UserName),
                new Claim(Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };
                string SecurKey = Startup.StaticConfig.GetSection("Authentication:SecurityKey").Value;
                var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurKey));
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration.GetSection("Authentication:ValidIssuer").Value,
                    audience: _configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Audience").Value,
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
                    claims: claims,
                    signingCredentials: new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );
                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();

        }
```

I implement control that creates token, but when I tried authorizing with that I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:44383/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44383/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

Comment: Remove `options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to add support for JWT, we added the AddCookie and AddJwtBearer. Having websites require the token in the header would be a headache, especially for projects that aren’t purely SPA or API. So what I really wanted was support for both Cookies and JWTs.

In startup.cs you have:

```
    public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddDbContext<DualAuthContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DualAuthContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

      // Enable Dual Authentication 
      services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
          cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
          cfg.SaveToken = true;
          cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
          {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
          };
        });

      // Add application services.
      services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
      services.AddMvc();
    }
```

And In Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DataSeeder seeder)
{
  ...
  app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

After this in your controller that one you have used JWT, You should add JWT Bearer AuthenticationSchemes to Authorize attribute like this :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
  [Route("/api/customers")]
  public class ProtectedController : Controller
  {
    public ProtectedController()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
      return Ok(new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    }
  }
```

Refrence: [Two AuthorizationSchemes in ASP.NET Core 2](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2)

It's very simple and helpful to used.

Comment: does this mean, If you specify the route/endpoint for jwt or cooikes, then it cant used vice-versa? So any endpoint must have two respectively right?

Comment: another point Authorize Role is working fine , but policy is not

Comment: You should add Policy in ConfigureServices first then it work fine

Comment: it worked for cookies based but not jwt token

Comment: Which version of .NET Core you using? this base on asp.net core 2.2 and for other version this is deferent!

Comment: i use dotnet 5.0

Comment: in .NET Core 5 this is deferent, see Microsoft Document, .NET 5 is like 3.1 but some features are deferent, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: completely using jwt token for authentication and authorisazation