# Is Authorization Policy requireAuthenticatedUser compatible with multiple forms of authentication (cookie and JWT)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC Application with a web API. I'm using cookie auth for MVC pages and JWT Bearer auth for API. I followed the solution described [How can i implement Cookie base authentication and jwt in asp.net core 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093946/how-can-i-implement-cookie-base-authentication-and-jwt-in-asp-net-core-2-2) which is based on https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2

The trouble comes when I want to add an authorization policy to ensure the entire site is available to authenticated users

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
```

When I do this, the JWT Bearer authentication is ignored even though the atrribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` is present. Thus accessing these API controllers returns a redirect to the login page.

How could I enable the authorization policy and still maintain both forms of authentication? A workaround is to add `[Authorize]` attribute to all controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the jwt bearer schema and asp.net identity authentication schema when building `AuthorizationPolicy` :

```
var policy = new  AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme })
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
```

So that both authenticated by asp.net identity and JWT token authentication could access your protected actions .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a known issue in the .Net core. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and it is still not resolved.

Here is my workaround:

```
 var principal = context.User;
        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);  //user not logged in
        }
```