# ASP.NET Core 8 Default Identity token based auth not working - 404 Not Found error

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

I am trying to explore on the Identity token based authentication in **.NET core 8 Web API** app. I was able to register user, generate & store token. However when I tried to access authorized api it's failing, redirecting to the /Account/login endpoint. Note I have added [Authorize] attr for my own API/Action. Based on my analysis it's redirecting to /Account/Login because API doesn't have this endpoint , hence it is throwing 404 instead of 401. My concern is why it is even failing to Authenticate.

> I tried multiple configurations to get it work but none is helping,
> Please guide here.

**N.B**
I am successfully able to use Jwt token, I want to use the default Identity for token management rather than JWT. Referenced [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0) but I am missing it somewhere.

**Code:**
Prog

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);  
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );
    builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    
    builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); // Ensures to use default AspNet token providers
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme); // tried few options but same error
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    
    /* This is working as expected
    var issuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Get<string>();
    var audience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience").Get<string>();
    var secretKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey").Get<string>();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(
        options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = issuer,
                ValidAudience = audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey))
            };
        });
    */
    
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IJwtService, JwtService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IAspTokenService, AspTokenService>();
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost("register")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var appUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserId, Email = model.Email, NewAddress = model.Address };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        //var token = _jwtService.GenerateToken(model.UserId);
        var token = await _aspTokenService.GenerateAndStoreTokenAsync(appUser.UserName);
        return Ok(token);
    }

    return BadRequest(result.Errors);
}

[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserId);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        //var token = _jwtService.GenerateToken(user.UserName);
        var token = await _aspTokenService.GenerateAndStoreTokenAsync(user.UserName);
        return Ok(token);
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}

[HttpGet("securedata")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetSecureData()
{
    string token = string.Empty;
    var usersCliams = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    foreach (var claim in usersCliams?.Claims)
    {
        if ("Id".Equals(claim.Type))
        {
            token = claim.Value.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return Ok(new { Message = $"Id {token}" });
}
```

Service

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public AspTokenService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<TokenDto> GenerateAndStoreTokenAsync(string username)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, user.Id);
    await _userManager.SetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, user.Id, token);
    return new TokenDto { Token = token };
}

public async Task<TokenDto> GetTokenAsync(string username)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var token = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, user.Id);
    return new TokenDto { Token = token };
}
```

Other

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
     public string? NewAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

DB table mapping - check user Manu123456, ignore other two

[image: DB table mapping - check user Manu123456, ignore other]

Comment: Hi, something is bothering me, you say `redirecting to the /Account/login endpoint` how an API can redirect you to another route when nothing is specified in the controller? It is your client application who does that, not your API. Can you provide the code that call the `securedata` route ?

Comment: @Max, By default It's done internally by .NET in assumption that the retrieved token (Check above register API) is invalid. I am using POSTMAN to call the API with header as Bearer token that's it nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net 8, there are built-in jwt endpoints now for asp.net identity.
Install package`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`
Instead of `AddIdentity`,try use following codes

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
...
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
```

Reference: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-introducing-the-identity-api-endpoints/
`AddIdentity` is commonly used for MVC project.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks for sharing diff between AddIdentity vs AddIdentityCore, however my whole intension was use my own endpoint to authenticate  post user is registered. Means if I have token on registering user, then user should be authorized to all [Authorize] endpoints. As client I need to make 2 calls (if direct Authorize is not working), one for login(which is again not my app API) to get token, then call Authorize endpoints. 
Hence is it safe to conclude this scenario is not possible ?

Comment: @user2618875 My apologies it should be `AddIdentityApiEndpoints`. Once you get the external token, you can use token information to login your own api to generate your own token.  You surely could request every authorized endpoints with carrying your own token. Do I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Do you mean I need first external token to get valid token ? And then use it for Authorization ?

Comment: @user2618875 No, seems I misunderstand "not my app API".  I have no idea why you say this scenario is not possible.

Comment: @user2618875 `AddIdentity`actually is requesting "cookie" which you don't have,so authorize cannot pass. If You are trying using jwt bearer token, I think you should use `AddIdentityApiEndpoints`.

Comment: As per MS Docs if useCookies is omitted in request as query param then it will fallback to default token auth. So not sure why it should fail ?

Comment: @user2618875 I'm not sure about that, could post doc link?  And you could check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/56123064/20240963

Comment: I tried Jwt it's working fine. I am iterrested more in Identity token auth in pure Web API. 

*Token-based authentication
If useCookies is false or omitted, token-based authentication is enabled. The response body includes the following properties:*
link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @user2618875 Thanks for sharing. This doc is using `AddIdentityApiEndpoints` , do you also try it?